# Flutter error: no such ancestor exist DefaultTabController

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

```
Scaffold(
    drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(padding: EdgeInsets.zero, children: <Widget>[
      DrawerHeader(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.red[700],
        ),
        child: Text(
          'Drawer Menu',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
        ),
      ),
      if (widget.accessValue!.contains('EAMSWEBEXTUSER') &&
          widget.accessValue!.contains('EAMSWEBEXTAPPRVR')) ...[
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Material Requisition Order'),
          onTap: () {
            Get.to(homePage(
              accessValue: widget.accessValue,
            ));
          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('MRO Approvals'),
          onTap: () {
            Get.to(ApprovalMain(
              accessValue: widget.accessValue,
            ));
          },
        )
      ] else if (widget.accessValue!.contains('EAMSWEBEXTUSER')) ...[
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Material Requisition Order'),
          onTap: () {
            Get.to(homePage(
              accessValue: widget.accessValue,
            ));
          },
        )
      ] else if (widget.accessValue!.contains('EAMSWEBEXTAPPRVR')) ...[
        ListTile(
          title: Text('MRO Approvals'),
          onTap: () {
            Get.to(ApprovalMain(
              accessValue: widget.accessValue,
            ));
          },
        )
      ] else if (widget.accessValue!.contains('EAMSWEBEXTWRHSMN')) ...[
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Material Issuance Receipt'),
          onTap: () {
            Get.to(MIRMain(
              accessValue: widget.accessValue,
            ));
          },
        )
      ] else
        Container()
    ])),
    appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1),
          child: Image.asset("lib/assets/cepyelow.png",
              fit: BoxFit.contain, height: 25),
        )),
    body: listOfScreens[selectedIndex],
    bottomNavigationBar: ConvexAppBar(
      style: TabStyle.react,
      backgroundColor: Colors.red[700],
      items: [
        TabItem(icon: Icons.content_paste),
        TabItem(icon: Icons.library_books_outlined),
        TabItem(icon: Icons.forward_to_inbox)
      ],
      initialActiveIndex: 0,
      onTap: onItemTapped,
    ),
  ),
```

Hello, im trying to resolve this error. can't determine whats the problem on my code. (see picture of error and code above). I'm using the convex_bottom_bar widget. Hope someone can help me regarding this issue.

This was working fine 3months ago. and now i tried to run my app and got this error. Maybe flutter pub upgrade did something that made some widget deprecated.